# RelativeLayout is returning LinearLayout LayoutParams

Tags: android, android-linearlayout, android-relativelayout

Here is a snippet from my layout xml that defines my RelativeLayout.

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/npvirrButtons"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    >
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonNPVLabel"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonIRR_NFV"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Here is where I save the reference to it.

```
this.npvirrButtons = (RelativeLayout)this.findViewById(R.id.npvirrButtons);
```

Then later when I try to change the height from `0dp` to `wrap_content`, I grab the layout params like this:

```
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams)this.npvirrButtons.getLayoutParams();
```

But I get an exception thrown:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.LinearLayout$LayoutParams cannot be cast to android.widget.RelativeLayout$LayoutParams
    at com.mydomain.myapp.MyActivity.calculateIRR(MyActivity.java:564)
```

Why is my RelativeLayout returning a LinearLayout params object?

Comment: try to rerun the project after removing gen & bin folder

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`getLayoutParams()` returns the current LayoutParameters of the view according to its parent. So, `buttonIRR_NFV` will return `RelativeLayout.LayoutParameter`.

Think about it this way: `getLayoutParams()` is a method you call to alter the current view's position on its container. If you want to modify the way you layout one of your children, you have to get its LayoutParameters instead.